# Return latest value present in power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, nonblank

I am trying to create a calculated column in power BI called most recent score that gives me the most recent score for each employee.

```js
Employee Number Date Score Most recent score 
1234 01/01/2019 1 1
1235 01/01/2019 4 2
1236 01/01/2019 2 3
1288 01/01/2019 0 0
1259 01/01/2019 0 1
1234 01/02/2019 3 1
1235 01/02/2019 4 2
1236 01/02/2019 1 3
1288 01/02/2019 2 0
1259 01/02/2019 4 1
1234 01/03/2019 1 1
1235 01/03/2019 2 2
1236 01/03/2019 3 3
1288 01/03/2019 0 0
1259 01/03/2019 1 1
1234 01/04/2019 BLANK 1
1235 01/04/2019 BLANK 2
1236 01/04/2019 BLANK 3
1288 01/04/2019 BLANK 0
1259 01/04/2019 BLANK 1
```

---

I am using the below measure which seems to work unless the most recent score is a "0" in which case it pulls through the most recent non "0" score.

```
Most Recent Score =
VAR MRSM = Master[Employee ID]
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        LASTNONBLANK ( Master[Score], Master[Score] ),
        FILTER ( Master, Master[Employee ID] = MRSM )
    )
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please format code as code (including tabular data). Nobody can read this as it is now ...

Comment: Sorry, have done this now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDITED ANSWER**

This seems to do what you need.

```
Most Recent Score = 
VAR EmpID = 'Master'[Employee ID]
VAR tblScores =
    FILTER ('Master', 'Master'[Employee ID] = EmpID  && NOT ( ISBLANK ( 'Master'[Score] ) )
    )
VAR mrsDate = CALCULATE ( MAX ( [Date] ), tblScores )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Master'[Score] ), FILTER ( tblScores, 'Master'[Date] = mrsDate )
    )
```

---

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for this however when I used it I only received blanks through. Completely my fault as I left the fact that there were also blanks in the score column as not every employee gets a score every month. Really sorry! I've had a go at amending your code to cope with this but not cracked it. I've amended the question to make the table clearer. Any chance you can help?

Comment: Is the [most recent score] column in your visual the result you want? If not then please ad a column with the result you are after.

Comment: Yes most recent score is the desired result